# Facebook Open Graph Debugger bug?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect, facebook-opengraph

I have recently renewed my website, but for some reason the [Facebook Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) is not able to re-scrape my new og tags.

When I enter the website, I receive a couple of error messages which makes no sense.

For example: 
1.Circular redirect path detected (see 'Redirect Path' section for details).
2. URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed.

When I debug my website, and see which HTML status code is given, it is 200 OK. So where does the 301 come from which the Facebook Debugger detects?

What am I missing in my set up?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting error have happened to me on websites that redirect http to https. 
The errors output explains explicitly what is the path the debugger needed to pass. In my case it showed me that it had to pass the following path: `https >> http >> https`.

This have occurred since the page url i tried to share used https, but in the `op meta` definition, I have defined it as `http`. Fixing that resolved all.